# Node.js interacting with Website

Tags: php, html, node.js, request, xmlhttprequest

So I have this node.js app that I am running on my computer which receives items from steam users and I want the app to be able to send the item information received via some sort of method to a website to store on a db. The part where I store the info in a db should be easy if I can get the info to the php stage. And no I can't just directly send the data to a mySQL server (I know this can be done), because my website host doesn't allow remote SQL connections. :( The problem is I don't know how to setup a communication method between the node.js app and site, preferably using php on the site end.

The method I thought of was if I could somehow use http requests to send json data or something simple like that detailing the item information. And this is what I have so far to work with.

On the website side:

```
<?php
/* register.php */

header("Content-type: text/plain");
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Data\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = $_POST . $_GET . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Its a simple way of logging what data is inputed to this page.

And in node.js:

```
/* sendrequest.js */
var sys = require('util');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    sys.puts("State: " + this.readyState);

    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        sys.puts("Complete.\nBody length: " + this.responseText.length);
        sys.puts("Body:\n" + this.responseText);
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "www.my-site.com/register.php");
xhr.send();
```

I tried using this to send data to the php script but that just returned this.

```
State: 1
State: 1
(node:7328) DeprecationWarning: util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead
.
State: 2
State: 3
State: 4
Complete.
Body length: 851
Body:
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>funct
ion toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))})
;return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].cons
tructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":""
)+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c
63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("e701
ec1290eafb233a5b83622b74d5f1");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c
,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://
name.byethost10.com/trade/db_interact.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requ
ires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a brows
er with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Which as I understand it, tells me that I did something wrong in the transmission stage from node.js.

So thats my problem, I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.
Also, sorry if this is not explained properly.

Thanks in advance,

Durgen

---

**EDIT:** Ok, so I narrowed it down to something php/server side. Because, I use this node.js script with this php script on a locally hosted server and got it to send and receive alright.

node.js script

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/db_interact.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {'mes': 'testing'}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```

db_interact.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Data\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = $_POST['mes'] . $_POST . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
echo "done\n";
$txt = $_POST['mes'];
echo $txt . "\n";
echo "worked?";
?>
```

Now my only question is why won't it work on the other server?

Comment: There are literally thousands of ways to send data from one server to another.,  A classic way is to use http and send an http post with the data in the post and then on your other end you have an http server with a request handler for that post who can grab the data out of the post and put it in the sql database.  Since this will presumably be on the open internet, you will probably want to require some credentials with the post.  There are at least 1000 other ways to do this.  You can use the `request` library for node.js to send an http post to any other server.

Comment: This is nearly exactly what i am going for, but I can't find the info you speak of online. So, some direct links or usage examples would be very helpfull.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but you can search for "npm request" and that will find the request library.

Comment: K thanks. I have already looked at that, but I'll have another good look at it. Thanks again.

Comment: It means `request` success. Check your `php` project, is there have any interceptors to response the result you don't want, or something like `http 301 redirect`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issues are the XRH isn't sending any data to the server. It should be something like:

```
xhr.send(YOUR_DATA_HERE)
```

(See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) for more information on how to use the send method) and the PHP needs to `echo` some output after you save the data, or it will return the HTML document to the Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the info and examples on the page you linked to are going to give me some more answers. Is this a standard/normal way to send data between such things?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. You might also try sending the data from Javascript in [JSON format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it in PHP.